# Complete usable Debian wheezy image on 1 dvd

Tags: debian

Is it possible to have a complete Debian wheezy installon on 1 dvd. I find it split up into 3 dvd's on the site.

https://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/

I just want to have a good install as the debian installer can't seem to connect over wifi.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a 'complete' install using the first image (CD or DVD).  The other images are rarely if ever necessary unless you will literally never connect the machine to the network later.

I'd recommend doing your installation from the first CD image and then after the first reboot you should be able to connect normally and use `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` to download & install any needed updates.   Then just use `apt-get` to install new programs as desired.